Was there a global FIDE rating peak during 2019 up to early 2020
Magnus' peak rating of 2882 was achieved during 2014 May and again in 2019 August. I also noticed that many club level people I know who played actively peaked in rating during the 2019-2020. This is obviously an observation and not a proven statistic.
I don't recall any special change happening with the FIDE rating system during that period like introduction of K40, or the recent rating addition to keep minimum rating 1400.
Is my observation accurate?
